# Mongo Mdbc powershell

Tags: mongodb, powershell

i'm using mongo mdbc cmdlet with powershell to connect to my mongodb atlas without LDAP and it work fine(i use scram auth).

Also, i'm trying to connect to another mongodb atlas configured in LDAP but i got this error:

[image]

connection don't return any error but when i go to getdb i receve that error.

If can help here connection string used with mongoshell(works fine):

```
mongo "mongodb://user:pass@hostname/?authMechanism=PLAIN&authSource=%24external&retryWrites=true&readPreference=primaryPreferred" --tls --tlsAllowInvalidHostnames --tlsAllowInvalidCertificates
```

we add `--tls --tlsAllowInvalidHostnames --tlsAllowInvalidCertificates` in more respect powershell

THnaks for the help

Comment: that is one heinous screenshot.

Comment: The issue is discussed and resolved here -- https://github.com/nightroman/Mdbc/issues/40

Comment: Hi Roman, yes resolved there i forgot to write here. Thanks